# Объект по большим координатам

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Как правильно вывести на экран например прямоугольник с координатами х,у больше 100000. Пока получается сформировать canvas с размерами от 0.0 до max(x,y) и линиями начертить этот объект. Таким образом я знаю что он в правом нижнем углу. 
Как автоматически на нем сфокусироваться ? или вывести в canvas только этот объект, т.е. размером от min(x,y) до max(x,y) объекта.